# Req has no body when posting with Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, postman

I'm learning about REST with node.

I'm trying to use post to add an element to my db.

My code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var AdModule = require('../models/ad');

router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        AdModule.find((err, col) => {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(col);
        })
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        var ad = new AdModule();
        ad.title = req.body.title;
        ad.desc = req.body.desc;
        ad.price = req.body.price;
        ad.save(err => {
            if (err)
                res.send('err' + err);
            res.json({msg: 'Created'});
        })
        res.json(req);
    });

module.exports = router;
```

When using post I get `req.body` is undefined.

My server.js code:

```
'use strict';

//======================= Base setup =======================\\

var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./globals/config');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var ads = require('./routes/ads');

var app = express();


//========================= DB =============================\\

mongoose.connect(config.db, () => {
    console.log('Connected');
});


//========================= Routes =========================\\

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/ads', ads);

//========================= Parsers ========================\\

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
// app.set('view engine', 'html');

//========================= 404 ============================\\

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//     var err = new Error('Not Found');
//     err.status = 404;
//     next(err);
// });
//
// // error handler
// app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
//     // set locals, only providing error in development
//     res.locals.message = err.message;
//     res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
//
//     // render the error page
//     res.status(err.status || 500);
//     res.render('error');
// });
//

//==========================================================\\

module.exports = app;
```

So I am using body parser.

This is how I'm posting with postman:

[image]

What can be the reason for this madness?

I'm guessing it's something with server.js but have no idea what.

I was following this tutorial.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4#creating-routes-for-a-single-item

Comment: Your question is answered by your tutorial.

Comment: I didn't realize the order mattered in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express middlewares executed by order that they are defined, in your case `bodyParser` defined after `ads` middleware, just move `asd` to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Put your parsers above your routes -- as it happens now, requests are hitting the routes before they have a chance to go through the parsers.